# Login to Domain Controller fails if using DC=,DC=, but works with FQDN

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am trying to reproduce an error with AD credentials, and I can reproduce the problem my code has in ADSI Edit as follows:

I have the domain `contoso.local` with path `DC=CONTOSO,DC=local`.

When using the path `LDAP://contoso.local/Default Naming Context` I can login with credentials `CONTOSO\testuser`. However, when using path `LDAP://DC=CONTOSO,DC=local/Default Naming Context`, I get the error that the credentials are wrong.

So it works when I use the `Domain.Name`, but when I get the path from RootDSE's `defaultNamingContext` property, which uses the `DC=` notation, it fails.

Since the credentials are correct: what is the underlying issue here, and where do I find documentation how to circumvent these quirks?

Comment: does the distinguished name contain a comma or other special character maybe (in any name part)? In that case, you should escape this with a backslash: `cn=Last, First` --> `cn=Last\, First`

Comment: Is the computer you are running this from joined to either the same domain, or a trusted domain?